# Is there a closed-form solution for the following integral?

Tags: normal-distribution, integral

The integral under consideration is as follows:
$$
F=\int_{a}^{1} \exp\Big\{c\Phi^{-1}(x+b) + d\Big\}\; \mathrm dx,
$$
where $0<a, b<1$, and $c>0, d\in\mathbb{R}$ are constants, and the notation $\Phi(\cdot)$ denotes the standard normal distribution function given by
$$
\Phi(z) = \mathbb{P}(Z\leq z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{z}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\; \mathrm du.
$$

Comment: Using the substitution $y=\Phi^{-1}(x+b)$, you should be able to work out the closed form solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that it works.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Gordon's help, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
F=exp\Big\{d + \frac{{c}^2}{2}\Big\}\Big[ \Phi\Big(\Phi^{-1}\Big(1+b\Big)-{c}\Big)- \Phi\Big(\Phi^{-1}\Big(a+b\Big)-{c}\Big)\Big]
\end{eqnarray*}